# Facebook :getLoginStatus returns "connected" when not connected

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

After having ensured that my Facebook account no longer has the app attached, running getLoginStatus still returns that I am connected. This is the code I'm using:

```
// Load the Facebook SDK asynchronously
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : <My App Id>,
        version    : 'v12.0',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        status     : true
    });

    if ( !ih.data.fb.current_access_token )
    {
        // FB initialized, call getLoginStatus for status
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            console.log("Got login status, calling handler:", response);
            statusChangeCallback(response, false);
        }, true);
    }
};
```

This returns an authResponse:

```
authResponse: 
    accessToken: <An Access Token>
    data_access_expiration_time: 1686002578
    expiresIn: 5111072
    graphDomain: "facebook"
    signedRequest: <A signed request>
    userID : <My FB Account UserId>
    loginSource: "facebook"
    status: "connected"
```

Using the access token debugger, the access token returned is:

```
App ID  <My App Id> : <My App Name>
Type    User
App-Scoped User ID <My user Id> : <User Name>  User last installed this app via API N/A 
Issued  1678226578 (20 hours ago)
Expires 1683410578 (in about 2 months)
Data Access Expires 1686002578 (in about 3 months)
Valid   True
Origin  Web
Scopes  email, pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_posts, public_profile

Granular Scopes
pages_show_list <My Page Id> : Test page
pages_read_engagement   <My Page Id> : Test page
pages_manage_posts  <My Page Id> : Test page
```

Does the getLoginStatus function return "connected" if the app was ever connected in the past? Or am I doing/interpreting this wrong?

Added thought: This app "belongs" to my account (it's a test app cloned from an app that this account is an admin for). Could that be causing the problem?

Thanks...

Comment: Sounds like it did not actually get removed from the account. If you have granted an app permissions in the past already (and they have not been explicitly revoked), then you are not supposed to be asked for them again. Try and remove all granted permissions in Graph API Explorer.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked. But since I can't ask my clients to go into the Graph Explorer, I'm not sure how to proceed (outside of my test case). I had gone into "Settings & Privacy -> Settings -> Apps and Websites" and removed the app there, shouldn't that have worked?

Comment: Proceed with what, exactly? Which actual _problem_ is there to solve here?